# Call controller method from Application during initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby rails/ mongdodb for my application where I do not have static pre-defined classes for my models but I maintain some meta data and create all classes dynamically during run time.

Now I want to initialize my classes when I startup the rails application:

```
module WSAServer
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.1

     config.after_initialize do
      puts 'Initialize server'
      Entity.all.each do |entity|
        puts 'initialize', entity.label
        DataController::getObject(entity)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To initialize all my classes I loop through the metadata (Through each Entity) and want to call the method getObject() from my controller which creates a new class if not yet existing. Doing so I am getting the error: method getObject not existing for DataController.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Thanks,Michael

Comment: Define your method inside DataController as `def self.getObject` instead of `def getObject`. In addition, by convention, I suggest renaming it to `get_object`

Comment: Since it can also initialize the object, I'd call it `find_or_initialize_object`. (I assume that you renamed it to `Object` only for the sake of this question. In a real application, `Object` isn't a good name.) Furthermore, the question is whether `DataController` also initializes internal state associated with `Entity`. In that case, better have a method `setup_entities` and leave the responsibility of iterating over all entities to the controller.

Comment: Yes - forget about the naming. But even changing the method to def self.getObject results in this error: ¸<class:Application>': undefined method `getObject' for DataController:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: Stop! Works now! I called a second method within getObject and this wasnt working - but changing this to self.xxx made it work! Thanks a lot!!!